# How to upload spfile to document library?

Tags: 2013, picture-library, spfile

I am creating new web in the ItemAdded event receiver and I want to upload the picture that is attached with the item to the newly created site's picture library and if no attachment is there then I want to upload the Sharepoint's blank image file which has the path. `_layouts/15/images/256_icgen.png`

My code is:

```
newWeb = properties.Web.Webs.Add(url, url, desc, 1033, Webs.Community.WebTemplate, true, false);
newWeb.Lists.Add("CommunityPicture", string.Empty, SPListTemplateType.PictureLibrary);
newWeb.Update();
if (item.Attachments.Count > 0)
{
    string attachUrl = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(item.Attachments.UrlPrefix, "/" + item.Attachments[0]);
    string fileName=StoreAttachmentToPicLib(attachUrl,properties.Web,newWeb);

    item.Attachments.Delete(fileName);
    item.Update();
}
else
{
    string attachUrl = "_layouts/15/images/256_icgen.png";                        
    string fileName = StoreAttachmentToPicLib(attachUrl, properties.Web, newWeb);
}
private string StoreAttachmentToPicLib(string attachUrl,SPWeb ListWeb,SPWeb newWeb)
{
    //List web is All Communities web which will refer to communities list and the newWeb is the subsite of community.
    SPFile oFile = ListWeb.GetFile(attachUrl);
    string fileName = oFile.Name;
    byte[] binFile = oFile.OpenBinary(); // error comes here "Cannot open file"

    SPFolder library = newWeb.Folders["CommunityPicture"];
    library.Files.Add("HomePic.jpg", binFile, true);
    library.Update();
    return fileName;
}
```

My problem is that I the file `oFile` is found successfully but when the control reaches to OpenBinary() error is thrown.

Am I going through right way or what am I missing in my code?

Comment: can you post the error here? sorry just noticed the error ;)

Comment: I am debugging and let you know

Comment: Cannot open file "_layouts/15/images/256_icgen.png".

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to get the file!

```
public static SPFile GetFileObject(this SPWeb web, string url)
{
  object o = web.GetFileOrFolderObject(url);
  if (o is SPFile)
  {
    return (SPFile)o;
  }
  else
  {
    throw new FileNotFoundException();
  }
}
```

Call the method above like so:

```
SPFile oFile = GetFileObject(ListWeb,attachUrl);
```

It shouldn't break then as it's getting the file properly! Something to do with how you build the url together, either it will show false or true.

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-spwebgetfilestring/

You can whilst debugging hover over `oFile` and see its values and if they are correct.

**EDIT**

just noticed what your trying todo!

you should do this instead!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125529/office-365-sharepoint-upload-files-to-documents-library

what you are trying todo is this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms477413.aspx

which wont work.

Comment: should url be full url or relative?

Comment: GetFileOrFolderObject is relative, but the site can be the site collection url.

Comment: I am getting oFile successfully but the error comes when I call OpenBinary() method

Comment: ok im presuming that the account that your using has permission to open the file?

Comment: yes sir, I manually changed the permission of that file in the 15 hive

Comment: just ammended my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code that works that runs in a feature event receiver

```
SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;

//Get the image from site collection root style library
SPWeb fromWeb = web.Site.RootWeb;            
SPFile imgFile = fromWeb.GetFile("Style Library/Images/logo.png");

//convert to binary
byte[] picFile = imgFile.OpenBinary();
string fileName = imgFile.Name;

SPList list = web.Lists["Media"];
SPFolder picLibrary = list.RootFolder;

//Add to the right folder in current site
picLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, picFile, true);
list.Update();
```